# how to do not calculate duplicate record of group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report in crystal report. In the detail part it shows like these which has duplicate record

[image]

When i total amount, i do not want to calculate the duplicate records.

I try to write the running total fomula in the running total fields
(Item) <> Previous (Item) 
then i get the result. the red number
[image]

There is something wrong, but i just do not know how can i fix it. thanks

Comment: Instead of using a formula in the Running Total, use "On Change of Field" and pick the item's key.

Comment: I did that, but that still not working. I will keep on trying. Thanks for your respond

Comment: You want to display the duplicate records but only in sum u want to avoid the duplicate records, right?

Comment: Actually, I do not display the duplicate records